# Взятие структуры из класса

Tags: c++, классы

в `сlass Points` имеется структура

```
    public:
    Points();
    virtual ~Points();

    struct node
    {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
    };

private:
    node uzl;
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы в основном файле `main.cpp` я не создавал снова эту структуру, а пользовался созданной в классе? Потому что на данный момент основной файл выглядит так:

```
#include "Points.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node 
{
float x;
float y;
float z;
};

int main(){
Points net;
node uzl1;
}
```

То есть я заново создаю структуру и применяю к ней методы класса

```
net.summ(uzl1) // что здесь - неважно
```

Answer (score 2):

Пользуйтесь структурой

```
Point::node
```

если я правильно понял ваш вопрос. Она объявлена как `publuc`, так что никаких проблем...

```
int main(){
    Points net;
    Points::node uzl1;
}
```

Только вы уж решите, `Point` или `Points` - а то в вопросе и так, и эдак...

Да и тут

```
#include Points.h
```

не помешали бы кавычки.

Comment: а если я буду создавать методы этого класса лучше работать с private: node uzl?

Comment: Зависит от того, где вы собираетесь с ними работать.